# Sigma Algebra Generator

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have some confusion regarding the definition of the generator of a sigma algebra. Looking at the wikipedia definition,

*'Let F be an arbitrary family of subsets of X. Then there exists a unique smallest σ-algebra which contains every set in F (even though F may or may not itself be a σ-algebra). It is, in fact, the intersection of all σ-algebras containing F. (See intersections of σ-algebras above.) This σ-algebra is denoted σ(F) and is called the σ-algebra generated by F'*

So why does this smallest such sigma algebra contain every set in $F$, for example the Borel sigma algebra is generated by $A = \{(a,b): a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$, why does it then follow that it contains all open intervals from this?

Comment: It is a well known fact that open sets in the real line are the union of countable disjoint intervals.

Comment: It's the smallest $\sigma$-algebra *that contains $F$*. It has to have every element of $F$ as an element because that's the definition of containment. (The wiki definition is being imprecise with contain, BTW. Perhaps that's the source of your confusion?)

Comment: By 'contains' $F$ do we mean contain everything in the set $F$, or have the set $F$ as an element of the $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: The first alternative. (For example (3,6) is in the Borel sigma algebra.) Your second alternative is not even structurally possible: $F \in P(P(X))$, while an element of the sigma-algebra would be an element of $P(X).$ So write $F \subset $ rather than $F \in.$

Answer (score 4):

You are misreading the statement. You seem to be reading it as "there exists a unique smallest $\sigma$-algebra" and that this $\sigma$-algebra "contains every set in $F$."

Rather, it should be read as "if we consider all $\sigma$-algebras that satisfy the property 'contains every set in $F$,' then there is a unique smallest $\sigma$-algebra among these $\sigma$-algebras." The proof is to consider the intersection of all these $\sigma$-algebras and recall that the arbitrary intersection of $\sigma$-algebras is itself a $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 1):

$\sigma(F)$ contains every set in $F$ by construction. That is, it is designed to contain every set in $F$. You should take the passage's advice and "See intersections of sigma algebras above." I am sure that above the article proves the lemma that any intersection of sigma algebras is again a sigma algebra.

In your particular example, let $\Omega$ be the collection of all sigma algebras $\Sigma$ that satisfy the condition $\Sigma \supset A$. You first need to make sure that $\Omega$ is not empty; then apply the lemma.

Do you now see that we can find every open interval in the family $$\bigcap_{\Sigma \in\Omega} \Sigma \quad ?$$